# google analytics event form submission

Tags: ajax, forms, google-analytics

I’ve done a lot of searching for this on StackOverflow and Google in general, and I’m surprised there isn’t an easier way to implement what we’re trying to do.

We are trying to set up a simple form conversion event to help us identify which sessions coming from different ads we are running are actually converting. We have the GA UTM codes set up correctly. We are using analytics.js (the newer Universal Google Analytics implementation) and Google Tag Manager, and we’re not using any other marketing software or analytics suite at this time.

Also, we do not have a “success page” (no success-event URL to tell Google to look for). Instead, when the form is correctly submitted, we make an Ajax request to accept the invitation, and Javascript displays a quick success message on the same page/URL.

It seems there needs to be three main parts to getting this information:
1. Set up Google Tag Manager and Analytics with event tracking to log clicks on our “Submit” button on our registration form
2. Set up a goal with Acquisition > Create Account and link it to our event tag 
3. Set up an Event Flow view in Analytics to track sessions based on UTM code to verify which ads are eventually reaching the goal

We're firing the event in the success callback of an Ajax call to create a new account:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'sign-ups', 'submit', 'new-account’);
```

It’s still not working. Any ideas what we might be missing?

Since it may be asked to see how we’ve configured things, I’ve taken a few screenshots. Thanks.

Summary of Workspace Changes:

[Our Tag Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HSqR.png)

[Our Trigger Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2TfP.png)

Comment: Can you please add more information how trigger is configured. It would be great, if you can share page url with this form. It will help me to provide for you working solutions

Comment: @VictorLeontyev, Our signup page is at [https://app.bluematador.com/ur/register](https://app.bluematador.com/ur/register). You'll need to enter your email and navigate to the confirmation page link in the email sent to you to see the code in question. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add more screenshot how you configured triggers

Comment: Sure, I'll try to add here, as StackOverflow limited my ability to post additional screenshots/links with a new account.

Comment: All screenshots: [￼http://imgur.com/a/r5njP](http://imgur.com/a/r5njP)

Need screenshots of anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your mistake.

In your confirmation page instead `ga('send', 'event', 'sign-ups', 'submit', 'new-account');` you should use `window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];window.dataLayer.push({'event': 'new-account'});`. Other GTM settings looks good

This image should explain how dataLayer and GTM works:
[image]

With datalayer you are sending event or some data to GTM, then inside GTM you can setup different triggers based on the info, what you received

Comment: Thanks, we're going to give this a try. What changes, if any, do we need to make in Google Tag manager or GA to make this implementation work?

Comment: Everything what you did in GTM was correct. You just need to send datalayer in thank you page

Comment: Thanks, the data layer worked. I've accepted your answer. Hope this question and answer can be archived for others who come across this same problem. It seems to be a basic tracking need, but a relatively complex implementation to get it to work.